# rsync doesn't copy files with restrictive permissions

Tags: rsync, file-permissions

Trying to copy files with rsync, it complains:

```
rsync: send_files failed to open "VirtualBox/Machines/Lubuntu/Lubuntu.vdi" \
(in media): Permission denied (13)
```

That file is not copied.  Indeed the file permissions of that file are very restrictive on the server side:

```
-rw-------    1 1000     1000     3133181952 Nov  1  2011 Lubuntu.vdi
```

I call rsync with

```
sudo rsync -av --fake-super root@sheldon::media /mnt/media
```

The rsync daemon runs as root on the server.  root can copy that file (of course).  rsyncd has "fake super = yes" set in /etc/rsyncd.conf.

What can I do so that the file is copied without changing the permissions of the file on the server?

Comment: If you use RSync as daemon on destination, please post `grep rsync /var/log/daemon` to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

As you appear to have root access to both servers have you tried a:  **--force** ?

Alternatively you could bypass the rsync daemon and try a direct sync e.g.

```
rsync -optg --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh --rsync-path=/usr/bin/rsync --verbose --recursive --delete-after --force  root@sheldon::media /mnt/media
```

Comment: Using ssh means encryption, which makes things slower. --force does only affect directories, if I read the man page correctly.

Comment: Unless your using ancient kit, the CPU overhead of encrypting / decrypting the traffic shouldn't be noticeable, but you will loose 10-20% of your bandwidth, through the encapsulation process. Then again 80% of a working link is better than 100% of a non working one :)

Comment: I _do_ have an "ancient kit".  ;-)  (Slow ARM CPU on a NAS.)  But I now mount the NAS with NFS and use rsync (with "sudo") locally.  This solves the problem (and is even faster).  However, I still think that my original problem must be solvable using the rsync protocol (remote, no ssh).